# How do I calculate the angle between the tangent to an outer circumference and a line passing through a specific point on the inner circumference?

Tags: geometry, circles, angle, tangent-line

I would like to calculate the angles indicated by the arrows in my sketch.
All I know is the segment AB between the two circumferences and the angles Theta and Theta'. The two circles are concentric, so I also know the distance between B and the centre.
Is there a quick clever procedure? I can't think of one.

[image]

Comment: You would need to know at least one more thing, such as the radius of one of the circles. Circles of different radius through the point $B$ give different angles.

Comment: The diagram suggests the two circles are concentric, and $AB$ passes through that centre - correct? You also need to know say the inner radius.

Comment: @Joffan Yes you are right they are concentric and hence I know the inner radius. Does it help?

Comment: @DavidK sorry they are concentric so I know the radius. How would I proceed from that?

Comment: Since you say you know the radius I believe you know the radius. Just keep in mind that this is **not** implied by concentric circles. You could have two circles of radius $1$ and radius $2$ and the segment $AB$ is one unit long. You could have two circles of radius $99$ and radius $100$ and the segment $AB$ is one unit long. If you told me everything you know about the segment $AB$ (its length, location, and orientation) I still wouldn't know whether the large circle's radius is $2$ or $100$ or something else. The reason I know you know the radius is because you told me you do.

Comment: @DavidK thanks, interesting side fact, but I'm struggling to see your suggestion on how to solve it.

Comment: I did not make any suggestion for a solution. I'm merely saying that your statement, "The two circles are concentric, so I also know the distance between B and the centre," is nonsense. If you think you can deduce the radius merely from the length $AB$ and the fact that the circles are "concentric" then you are not using the word "concentric" in the way the rest of us do. But if there is some other way to know the radius then you can use the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply sine rule to triangle $AOC$:
$$
{\sin\beta\over r}={\sin\alpha\over r+d}.
$$

[image]

Comment: Can I check to be sure: should it not be sin(180-alpha)/(r+d)?

Comment: @magnolia1 Yes, but $\sin(180°-\alpha)=\sin\alpha$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Reflections,_shifts,_and_periodicity